# Quantifying that near a point on a smooth hypersurface, it looks like a tangent hyperplane

Tags: convex-geometry

Suppose $C$ is a smoothly bounded convex body (*) in $\mathbb{R}^d$, and $p$ is a point on the boundary of $C$. Let $r>0$ and let $B(r)$ denote the ball of radius $r$ centered at $p$.

> Is it true that $\mbox{vol }(B(r) \cap
> > C) / \mbox{vol }(B(r)) \to 1/2$ as $r
> > \to 0$?

This seems obvious, but I can't seem to state a good reason why it's true.  Does it follow from some well-known theorem?

I would guess that we don't need convexity, and that something similar holds for smoothly embedded hypersurfaces in Euclidean space, and maybe one can relax "smooth" to class $C^2$?

(*)  My understanding is that "smoothly bounded convex body" means a compact, convex set, with nonempty interior, with a unique supporting hyperplane at each point.  I am not sure how close this is to a convex image of a smooth embedding of a $d$-dimensional ball, but again, I expect that the statement probably holds in either case.

Comment: call the tangent to C at p H. then H - p cuts the d-1 dimensional sphere to two pieces. For any point q on one of these halves, rq+p eventually lies inside C, and on the other side they lie out of C. Now use the fact that the d-1 dimensional sphere is compact and take a finite cover.

Comment: In other words, Taylor's theorem with remainders applied to a $C^1$ function. 

Comment: @Willie - sure, but you don't even need  the remainder - just that it's o(r).

Comment: Ooh boy, have I been using the terminology wrong all this time? For whatever reason I thought "...with remainders" just mean an error term $R_n(x) = o(|x|^n)$? I guess I was wrong. 

Comment: Thanks David, Willie.  I am slightly embarrassed to have asked such a simple question.  Is it bad MO form to delete this question -- it seems a bit elementary, but should I leave it in case it is helpful for someone else?

Comment: @Matthew: rather than asking here, you should ask on http://tea.mathoverflow.net/ (whether you should delete this question). Personally I am ambivalent, especially since there has been no answers given. And you can probably ask one of the moderators to close the question as no longer relevant (by either asking on Meta or flagging it). 

Comment: @Willie - I'm not sure about the terminology myself, that's what I remember (and it's been a while...). @Matthew, no reason for embarrassment - it happens to everyone once in a while; that being said I'd asked a moderator to close it (that's the reason I answered in a comment).